# Android plugin для Unity3d, после загрузки камеры перестают реагировать кнопки

Tags: unity3d, android, button

Android plugin для Unity3d, после загрузки камеры перестают реагировать кнопки.
Есть приложение, работающее с камерой, пишу для него plugin. Кнопки создаются в коде, им выдается onClick. До включения камеры кнопки можно нажать, после включения они становятся неактивными. Из-за чего это происходит, как исправить?